# Manipluating Pandas dataframe from group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Ok, here is my situation (leaving out uninteresting things):

Dataframe from a csv file, weher I get infos about the infentory of stores, like

Date,StoreID,…,InventoryCount

The rows are sorted by Date, but not sorted by StoreID, and the amount of stores can very in this time series.

What I want:

I want add a column to the Dataframe with the change in InventoryCount from one day to the previous one.
For that I was trying:

```
for name, group in df.groupby(["StoreID"]):

  for i in range(1, len(group)):

    group.loc[i, 'InventoryChange'] = group.loc[i, 'InventoryCount'] - group.loc[i-1, 'InventoryCount']
```

Comment: Have a look at `diff`, see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html

Comment: Thanks @ScootCork diff looks cool, but I also want to do calculation where I need the last 8 Days, the Diffrence was only the easyest example

Answer (score 0):

Your code explicitly iterates through the rows, which is a terrible idea in pandas, both aesthetically and performance wise. Instead, replace the last two lines by:

```
 group['InventoryChange'] = group[ 'InventoryCount'].diff(n)
```

Where `n` is the number of days you are interested in - 1 in your example, 8 in your comment.